# Sencha Cmd Package Build Not Working

Tags: extjs, package

Using SenchaCMD to create a package, I place the source code (some global methods I plan on sharing between my apps) in the src folder and attempt to build.

I get the following output:

```
Sencha Cmd v6.0.2.14
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Starting server on port : 1841
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/~cmd to /home/spsimmons/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.0.2.14...
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/ to /var/www/CpsWebApp/apps...
[INF] Package web server available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Writing concatenated output to file /var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/build/global-debug.js
[INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
[INF] Writing concatenated output to file /var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/build/global.js
[INF] merging 1 input resources into /var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/build/resources
[INF] merged 1 resources into /var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/build/resources
[INF] merging 10 input resources into /var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/build
[INF] merged 0 resources into /var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/build
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 2 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/.sencha/package/build-impl.xml:188: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/CpsWebApp/apps/packages/local/global/.sencha/package/slice-impl.xml:35: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

GlobalLib.js:

```
Ext.define('global.GlobalLib', {
    statics: {
        trim: function(input) {
            return input.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        },
        toUpperCase: function(input) {
            return input.toUpperCase();
        },
        toLowerCase: function(input) {
            return input.toLowerCase();
        },
        toTitleCase: function(input) {
            var smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|of|on|or|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;
            return input.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(match, p1, index, title) {
                if (index > 0 && index + p1.length !== title.length &&
                    p1.search(smallWords) > -1 && title.charAt(index - 2) !== ":" &&
                    title.charAt(index - 1).search(/[^\s-]/) < 0) {
                    return match.toLowerCase();
                }
                if (p1.substr(1).search(/[A-Z]|\../) > -1) {
                    return match;
                }
                return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
            });
        },
        ...
     }
});
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "global",
    "namespace": "global",
    "type": "code",
    "creator": "Shawn P. Simmons",
    "summary": "Global Methods for the CpsWebApp Application",
    "detailedDescription": "Global Methods for the CpsWebApp Application",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "compatVersion": "1.0.0",
    "format": "1",
    "output": "${package.dir}/build",
    "local": true,
    "sass" : {
        "namespace": "global",
        "etc": "${package.dir}/sass/etc/all.scss,${package.dir}/${toolkit.name}/sass/etc/all.scss",
        "var": "${package.dir}/sass/var,${package.dir}/${toolkit.name}/sass/var",
        "src": "${package.dir}/sass/src,${package.dir}/${toolkit.name}/sass/src"
    },
    "classpath": "${package.dir}/src,${package.dir}/${toolkit.name}/src",
    "overrides": "${package.dir}/overrides,${package.dir}/${toolkit.name}/overrides"
}
```

sencha.cfg:

```
# The folder that contains sub-packages of this package. Only valid for "framework"
# package type.
#
package.subpkgs.dir=${package.dir}/packages

#==============================================================================
# Custom Properties - Place customizations below this line to avoid merge
# conflicts with newer versions

package.cmd.version=6.0.2.14
package.framework = ext
```

It's becoming increasingly difficult to write code when I am continually running into show-stoppers like this. I don't see anything wrong with the configurations, I followed the documentation yet I am unable to complete this task. Does anyone have any insight on why this will not build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an internal error in Sencha Cmd while performing "slicing".
As a workaround, you could try skipping the "slice" build phase in your `build.properties`:

```
skip.slice=1
```

See https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_build.html#Build_Targets